# How to remove unwanted attributes from a JSON

Tags: json, deserialize

I have deserialized a JSON but the values are null. I suppose the issue here is the "Configurations". How can i remove/modify this so as the deserialization gets the proper values?

JSON

```
{"configurations":[{"guid":"xxxxxxxxxx","Type":"AutoCalculation","Amount":"50","In Advance Amount":""}]}
```

Apex class

```
public class el_GuaranteeJSON {

    public String Type;
    public String Amount;
    public String InAdvanceAmount;

}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: is the JSON property really `In Advance Amount` with embedded spaces?

Comment: yes it is as i have sent

Comment: I've linked a question that covers all of the basics of working with JSON in Apex. It includes suggestions on how to handle keys that are not valid Apex identifiers.